# Pyspark Stop Session stuck

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, dataproc

We have Pyspark job running in Google Dataproc cluster. Intermittently we are observing the job is stuck when we run SparkSession.stop() code. we enabled debug logs and below is the logs that we observe. Even after our code task is completed, the SparkSession.stop() code is stuck for some reason. Any help is appreciated.

Logs:

```
[2023-06-09 13:41:53] INFO: Stopping spark session...
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG com.google.cloud.spark.performance.DataprocMetricsListener: Collected 949 stages for application
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG com.google.cloud.spark.performance.DataprocMetricsListener: Collected 949 tasks
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG com.google.cloud.spark.performance.DataprocMetricsListener: Application completed time.. 1686318113554
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: stopping Server@1be16679{STARTED}[9.4.40.v20210413]
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.server.Server: doStop Server@1be16679{STOPPING}[9.4.40.v20210413]
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool: ran SparkUI-88-acceptor-0@d2fed33-ServerConnector@3e812e6{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:46653} in QueuedThreadPool[SparkUI]@7edd4748{STARTED,8<=16<=200,i=0,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@735d7819{s=0/20,p=0}]
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool: ran SparkUI-90-acceptor-2@d16a761-ServerConnector@3e812e6{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:46653} in QueuedThreadPool[SparkUI]@7edd4748{STARTED,8<=16<=200,i=1,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@735d7819{s=0/20,p=0}]
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool: ran SparkUI-89-acceptor-1@22cc90ed-ServerConnector@3e812e6{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:46653} in QueuedThreadPool[SparkUI]@7edd4748{STARTED,8<=16<=200,i=1,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@735d7819{s=0/20,p=0}]
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool: ran SparkUI-91-acceptor-3@3397565c-ServerConnector@3e812e6{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:46653} in QueuedThreadPool[SparkUI]@7edd4748{STARTED,8<=16<=200,i=3,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@735d7819{s=0/20,p=0}]
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandlerContainer: Graceful shutdown Server@1be16679{STOPPING}[9.4.40.v20210413] by 
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: stopping Spark@3e812e6{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:0}
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: stopping SelectorManager@Spark@3e812e6{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:0}
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: stopping ManagedSelector@49d8503e{STARTED} id=11 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Queued change lazy=false org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CloseConnections@aaa24f5 on ManagedSelector@49d8503e{STOPPING} id=11 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Wakeup on submit ManagedSelector@49d8503e{STOPPING} id=11 keys=0 selected=0 updates=1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@7e239f29 woken with none selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@7e239f29 woken up from select, 0/0/0 selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@7e239f29 processing 0 keys, 1 updates
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: updateable 1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: update org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CloseConnections@aaa24f5
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Closing 0 connections on ManagedSelector@49d8503e{STOPPING} id=11 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: updates 0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@7e239f29 waiting with 0 keys
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Queued change lazy=false org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$StopSelector@1b5769f4 on ManagedSelector@49d8503e{STOPPING} id=11 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Wakeup on submit ManagedSelector@49d8503e{STOPPING} id=11 keys=0 selected=0 updates=1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@7e239f29 woken with none selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@7e239f29 woken up from select, 0/0/0 selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@7e239f29 processing 0 keys, 1 updates
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: updateable 1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: update org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$StopSelector@1b5769f4
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: updates 0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool: ran org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$$Lambda$544/1757451567@1e1914a2 in QueuedThreadPool[SparkUI]@7edd4748{STARTED,8<=16<=200,i=4,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@735d7819{s=0/20,p=0}]
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: stopping EatWhatYouKill@40817be7/SelectorProducer@3fee2c48/IDLE/p=false/QueuedThreadPool[SparkUI]@7edd4748{STARTED,8<=16<=200,i=5,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@735d7819{s=0/20,p=0}][pc=0,pic=0,pec=0,epc=0]@2023-06-09T13:41:53.578Z
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: STOPPED EatWhatYouKill@40817be7/SelectorProducer@3fee2c48/IDLE/p=false/QueuedThreadPool[SparkUI]@7edd4748{STARTED,8<=16<=200,i=5,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@735d7819{s=0/20,p=0}][pc=0,pic=0,pec=0,epc=0]@2023-06-09T13:41:53.579Z
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: STOPPED ManagedSelector@49d8503e{STOPPED} id=11 keys=-1 selected=-1 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: stopping ManagedSelector@2f6f6561{STARTED} id=10 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Queued change lazy=false org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CloseConnections@14f0079c on ManagedSelector@2f6f6561{STOPPING} id=10 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Wakeup on submit ManagedSelector@2f6f6561{STOPPING} id=10 keys=0 selected=0 updates=1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@ede7761 woken with none selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@ede7761 woken up from select, 0/0/0 selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@ede7761 processing 0 keys, 1 updates
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: updateable 1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: update org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CloseConnections@14f0079c
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Closing 0 connections on ManagedSelector@2f6f6561{STOPPING} id=10 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: updates 0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@ede7761 waiting with 0 keys
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Queued change lazy=false org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$StopSelector@60b9ff57 on ManagedSelector@2f6f6561{STOPPING} id=10 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Wakeup on submit ManagedSelector@2f6f6561{STOPPING} id=10 keys=0 selected=0 updates=1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@ede7761 woken with none selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@ede7761 woken up from select, 0/0/0 selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@ede7761 processing 0 keys, 1 updates
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: updateable 1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: update org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$StopSelector@60b9ff57
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: updates 0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool: ran org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$$Lambda$544/1757451567@1998ca in QueuedThreadPool[SparkUI]@7edd4748{STARTED,8<=16<=200,i=5,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@735d7819{s=0/20,p=0}]
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: stopping EatWhatYouKill@2efb1364/SelectorProducer@7a6b2fb7/IDLE/p=false/QueuedThreadPool[SparkUI]@7edd4748{STARTED,8<=16<=200,i=6,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@735d7819{s=0/20,p=0}][pc=0,pic=0,pec=0,epc=0]@2023-06-09T13:41:53.581Z
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: STOPPED EatWhatYouKill@2efb1364/SelectorProducer@7a6b2fb7/IDLE/p=false/QueuedThreadPool[SparkUI]@7edd4748{STARTED,8<=16<=200,i=6,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@735d7819{s=0/20,p=0}][pc=0,pic=0,pec=0,epc=0]@2023-06-09T13:41:53.582Z
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: STOPPED ManagedSelector@2f6f6561{STOPPED} id=10 keys=-1 selected=-1 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: stopping ManagedSelector@6eb30b81{STARTED} id=9 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Queued change lazy=false org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CloseConnections@415f0247 on ManagedSelector@6eb30b81{STOPPING} id=9 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Wakeup on submit ManagedSelector@6eb30b81{STOPPING} id=9 keys=0 selected=0 updates=1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@2e04aa87 woken with none selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@2e04aa87 woken up from select, 0/0/0 selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@2e04aa87 processing 0 keys, 1 updates
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: updateable 1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: update org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CloseConnections@415f0247
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Closing 0 connections on ManagedSelector@6eb30b81{STOPPING} id=9 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: updates 0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@2e04aa87 waiting with 0 keys
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Queued change lazy=false org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$StopSelector@3749493b on ManagedSelector@6eb30b81{STOPPING} id=9 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Wakeup on submit ManagedSelector@6eb30b81{STOPPING} id=9 keys=0 selected=0 updates=1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@2e04aa87 woken with none selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@2e04aa87 woken up from select, 0/0/0 selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@2e04aa87 processing 0 keys, 1 updates
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: updateable 1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: update org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$StopSelector@3749493b
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: updates 0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool: ran org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$$Lambda$544/1757451567@20c34137 in QueuedThreadPool[SparkUI]@7edd4748{STARTED,8<=16<=200,i=6,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@735d7819{s=0/20,p=0}]
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: stopping EatWhatYouKill@147cdef2/SelectorProducer@626520ff/IDLE/p=false/QueuedThreadPool[SparkUI]@7edd4748{STARTED,8<=16<=200,i=7,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@735d7819{s=0/20,p=0}][pc=0,pic=0,pec=0,epc=0]@2023-06-09T13:41:53.584Z
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: STOPPED EatWhatYouKill@147cdef2/SelectorProducer@626520ff/IDLE/p=false/QueuedThreadPool[SparkUI]@7edd4748{STARTED,8<=16<=200,i=7,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@735d7819{s=0/20,p=0}][pc=0,pic=0,pec=0,epc=0]@2023-06-09T13:41:53.584Z
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: STOPPED ManagedSelector@6eb30b81{STOPPED} id=9 keys=-1 selected=-1 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: stopping ManagedSelector@5b115bce{STARTED} id=8 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Queued change lazy=false org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CloseConnections@26ecc106 on ManagedSelector@5b115bce{STOPPING} id=8 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Wakeup on submit ManagedSelector@5b115bce{STOPPING} id=8 keys=0 selected=0 updates=1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@5e6ba65d woken with none selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@5e6ba65d woken up from select, 0/0/0 selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@5e6ba65d processing 0 keys, 1 updates
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: updateable 1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: update org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CloseConnections@26ecc106
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Closing 0 connections on ManagedSelector@5b115bce{STOPPING} id=8 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: updates 0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@5e6ba65d waiting with 0 keys
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Queued change lazy=false org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$StopSelector@54151067 on ManagedSelector@5b115bce{STOPPING} id=8 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Wakeup on submit ManagedSelector@5b115bce{STOPPING} id=8 keys=0 selected=0 updates=1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@5e6ba65d woken with none selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@5e6ba65d woken up from select, 0/0/0 selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@5e6ba65d processing 0 keys, 1 updates
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: updateable 1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: update org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$StopSelector@54151067
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: updates 0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool: ran org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$$Lambda$544/1757451567@50ac43e0 in QueuedThreadPool[SparkUI]@7edd4748{STARTED,8<=16<=200,i=7,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@735d7819{s=0/20,p=0}]
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: stopping EatWhatYouKill@1f3cb0c2/SelectorProducer@4e2247c0/IDLE/p=false/QueuedThreadPool[SparkUI]@7edd4748{STARTED,8<=16<=200,i=8,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@735d7819{s=0/20,p=0}][pc=0,pic=0,pec=0,epc=0]@2023-06-09T13:41:53.588Z
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: STOPPED EatWhatYouKill@1f3cb0c2/SelectorProducer@4e2247c0/IDLE/p=false/QueuedThreadPool[SparkUI]@7edd4748{STARTED,8<=16<=200,i=8,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@735d7819{s=0/20,p=0}][pc=0,pic=0,pec=0,epc=0]@2023-06-09T13:41:53.588Z
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: STOPPED ManagedSelector@5b115bce{STOPPED} id=8 keys=-1 selected=-1 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: stopping ManagedSelector@e065bf3{STARTED} id=7 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Queued change lazy=false org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CloseConnections@72ecf47c on ManagedSelector@e065bf3{STOPPING} id=7 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Wakeup on submit ManagedSelector@e065bf3{STOPPING} id=7 keys=0 selected=0 updates=1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@48306db0 woken with none selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@48306db0 woken up from select, 0/0/0 selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@48306db0 processing 0 keys, 1 updates
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: updateable 1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: update org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CloseConnections@72ecf47c
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Closing 0 connections on ManagedSelector@e065bf3{STOPPING} id=7 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: updates 0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@48306db0 waiting with 0 keys
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Queued change lazy=false org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$StopSelector@82cf043 on ManagedSelector@e065bf3{STOPPING} id=7 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Wakeup on submit ManagedSelector@e065bf3{STOPPING} id=7 keys=0 selected=0 updates=1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@48306db0 woken with none selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@48306db0 woken up from select, 0/0/0 selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@48306db0 processing 0 keys, 1 updates
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: updateable 1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: update org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$StopSelector@82cf043
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: updates 0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool: ran org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$$Lambda$544/1757451567@46f79ac6 in QueuedThreadPool[SparkUI]@7edd4748{STARTED,8<=16<=200,i=8,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@735d7819{s=0/20,p=0}]
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: stopping EatWhatYouKill@546cbac1/SelectorProducer@6809ba7c/IDLE/p=false/QueuedThreadPool[SparkUI]@7edd4748{STARTED,8<=16<=200,i=9,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@735d7819{s=0/20,p=0}][pc=0,pic=0,pec=0,epc=0]@2023-06-09T13:41:53.595Z
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: STOPPED EatWhatYouKill@546cbac1/SelectorProducer@6809ba7c/IDLE/p=false/QueuedThreadPool[SparkUI]@7edd4748{STARTED,8<=16<=200,i=9,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@735d7819{s=0/20,p=0}][pc=0,pic=0,pec=0,epc=0]@2023-06-09T13:41:53.595Z
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: STOPPED ManagedSelector@e065bf3{STOPPED} id=7 keys=-1 selected=-1 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: stopping ManagedSelector@7dd3ec15{STARTED} id=6 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Queued change lazy=false org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CloseConnections@1292b504 on ManagedSelector@7dd3ec15{STOPPING} id=6 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Wakeup on submit ManagedSelector@7dd3ec15{STOPPING} id=6 keys=0 selected=0 updates=1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@69b6ee8d woken with none selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@69b6ee8d woken up from select, 0/0/0 selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@69b6ee8d processing 0 keys, 1 updates
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: updateable 1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: update org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CloseConnections@1292b504
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Closing 0 connections on ManagedSelector@7dd3ec15{STOPPING} id=6 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: updates 0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@69b6ee8d waiting with 0 keys
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Queued change lazy=false org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$StopSelector@2399bf25 on ManagedSelector@7dd3ec15{STOPPING} id=6 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Wakeup on submit ManagedSelector@7dd3ec15{STOPPING} id=6 keys=0 selected=0 updates=1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@69b6ee8d woken with none selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@69b6ee8d woken up from select, 0/0/0 selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@69b6ee8d processing 0 keys, 1 updates
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: updateable 1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: update org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$StopSelector@2399bf25
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: updates 0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool: ran org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$$Lambda$544/1757451567@67711dcb in QueuedThreadPool[SparkUI]@7edd4748{STARTED,8<=16<=200,i=9,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@735d7819{s=0/20,p=0}]
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: stopping EatWhatYouKill@6662b70/SelectorProducer@64b7cced/IDLE/p=false/QueuedThreadPool[SparkUI]@7edd4748{STARTED,8<=16<=200,i=10,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@735d7819{s=0/20,p=0}][pc=0,pic=0,pec=0,epc=0]@2023-06-09T13:41:53.597Z
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: STOPPED EatWhatYouKill@6662b70/SelectorProducer@64b7cced/IDLE/p=false/QueuedThreadPool[SparkUI]@7edd4748{STARTED,8<=16<=200,i=10,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@735d7819{s=0/20,p=0}][pc=0,pic=0,pec=0,epc=0]@2023-06-09T13:41:53.597Z
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: STOPPED ManagedSelector@7dd3ec15{STOPPED} id=6 keys=-1 selected=-1 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: stopping ManagedSelector@630a7fea{STARTED} id=5 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Queued change lazy=false org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CloseConnections@d048439 on ManagedSelector@630a7fea{STOPPING} id=5 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Wakeup on submit ManagedSelector@630a7fea{STOPPING} id=5 keys=0 selected=0 updates=1
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@34f6696 woken with none selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@34f6696 woken up from select, 0/0/0 selected
23/06/09 13:41:53 DEBUG org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@34f6696 processing 0 keys, 1 updates
```